# openpyxl loaded workbooks are empty

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

When I create my own workbook using openpyxl, I am able to save the active sheet, create new sheets, and then print out a list of all sheets in the workbook. When I load a pre-existing workbook, load_workbook appears to execute fine, but when I attempt to print out a list of sheets in the file or access the active sheet, the loaded workbook appears to be empty. The list of sheets in the workbook prints as an empty list, and saving the active sheet produces a None type object. My code:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

existing_book = load_workbook('existing_book.xlsx')
print(existing_book.sheetnames)
```

This workbook is not empty. It has several sheets. Yet, this prints an empty list.

```
[]
```

While this:

```
new_workbook = Workbook()
dest_name = "New_Workbook.xlsx"
main_sheet = new_workbook.active
main_sheet.title = "Main"
second_sheet = new_workbook.create_sheet("Sheet_2")
print(new_workbook.sheetnames)
```

prints the expected list of sheets. Why are my loaded workbooks... empty?
Furthermore, if I try to save one of my loaded workbooks, I get the error:

```
IndexError: At least one sheet must be visible
```

:-(

Comment: Cannot reproduce empty list symptom, same code for me prints a list of sheets: `[u'Sheet1', u'Sheet2']`, etc. Here's a live demo: https://repl.it/repls/WavyAccurateProfessional

Comment: Does this happen on _any_ existing xlsx? Or only for this particular _existing_book.xlsx_?

Comment: ok-- it seems that this only happens if the file was originally not an xlsx file, but had been saved as one in excel. The specific issue is with csv files. I can sort of intuit that there could be a problem there but not sure on the fix

Comment: OK-- issue fixed by importing csv file into excel through text import instead of simply saving opened csv file as xlsx.

Comment: You might have been hit by the same issue I just did. Made a quick note of it here: https://kenneho.net/2019/07/08/openpyxls-load_workbook-return-empty-list-of-sheets/

Answer (score 0):

you have to ## workbook.create_sheet(str) ##

Comment: El Chilango, Thanks for the answer. It also may be helpful to provide some context in your answer as to why this command is needed, and where it fits within the OP's code.